# Increase SQL Select Query Select to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

The requirements of a file I am working on is that each record should have a length of 1500, the problem is, the output will not show the entire row of data, it will stop at position 260. Is there a way to increase that?

The select statement below is an example:

```
SELECT SPACE(25) + 'C'
    + SPACE(80) + 'TT' + employeer_id
    + SPACE(80) + employee_id + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
    + SPACE(210) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), start_date, 112)
    + SPACE(200) + state + '1'
    + SPACE(150) + 'R'
    + SPACE(52) + address
    + SPACE(80)
```

Comment: Are you referring to the query results pane? If so, you can go to Options >> Query Results >> SQL Server >> Results to Text. There you can change the "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column:"

Comment: I cannot believe it, if it is a `vchar`, it should not limit you to 260, if the whole record only has 260 characters, you cannot get 1500.

Comment: Even if the display doesn't show all the characters, you can copy the record to the clipboard and paste it into your favorite text editor (Notepad++ is great for this) to see it all.

Please provide a sample record with data so we can try your query.

Comment: @Critical Error YES! Thank you!!!

Comment: @David You're welcome.

Comment: If I were you I would wrap all columns with Coalesce (or ISNull too) expressions just in case one of the values is bull it will return a value rather than a null.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a varchar limited field in there that's making SQL think the string needs to only be 260 characters. Are employee_id and employer_id fields strings? If not, you should CAST them in the query. If you're on a later version of SQL, you can try the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT TOP(1) OutputRow = CONCAT(
        SPACE(25) , 
        'C' , 
        SPACE(80) , 
        'TT' , 
        CAST([employeer_id] AS VARCHAR(25)) , 
        SPACE(80) , 
        CAST([employee_id] AS VARCHAR(25)) , 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) , 
        SPACE(210) , 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [start_date], 112) , 
        SPACE(200) , 
        [state] , 
        '1' , 
        SPACE(150) , 
        'R' , 
        SPACE(52) , 
        [address] , 
        SPACE(80)
    )
FROM [dbo].[YourTable] ;
```

Otherwise, try declaring a VARCHAR(1500) variable and assigning your value to it:

```
DECLARE @OutputRow VARCHAR(1501)
SELECT TOP(1) @OutputRow = 
    SPACE(25) + 
    'C' + 
    SPACE(80) + 
    'TT' + 
    CAST([employeer_id] AS VARHCAR(25)) + 
    SPACE(80) + 
    CAST([employee_id] AS VARHCAR(25)) + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + 
    SPACE(210) + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [start_date], 112) + 
    SPACE(200) + 
    [state] + 
    '1' + 
    SPACE(150) + 
    'R' + 
    SPACE(52) + 
    [address] + SPACE(80)
FROM [dbo].[YourTable] ;

SELECT @OutputRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this setting?  (under Tools | Options)

[image]

This setting does affect the output if you're using this script from another application, it only refers to the information displayed in SSMS.